# How do you debug django templates?

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-templates

Recently I learned about [Werkzeug's interactive debugger](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) in combination of [django_extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) to debug Django Python codes with `./manage.py runserver_plus`.

But how do you debug inside the templates? If I were to add some gibberish like `{{ yasdasdasf }}` inside my template, then Django will silently ignore it. What's more annoying is when you expect something to show up in the template, but it doesn't because there is an error.

I think I read some solutions about using `{{ debug }}` inside templates or `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` inside `settings.py`, but that seems like a lot of "turn on and off" for everytime you want to debug or check something in a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a crashing template filter:

```
@register.filter
def crash(request):
    crash_here
```

So `{{ request|crash }}` should raise an exception because crash_here is not defined, and you should be able to debug it in werkzeug.

Comment: Hmm I don't know. First of all `assert False` would be better than typing an undefined variable name. Second, that would only show the debug info about the Python code, not the template. Third, don't I have to create a `templatetags` folder, load the custom filter via `{% load something %}` inside the template, then type `{{ request|crash }}` after where I think the error is? Is there an easier solution? I don't mind using a IDE just for templates (but would rather now). Maybe I should use [Pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/)?

Comment: @hobbes3 why did you accept this answer, and any tool you are using now to debug and locate the exact place where the error is in Template?
Please let me know